# DialogFragment show steps with different "fragments"

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment, android-dialog

I want to show an `AlertDialog` that will have 3 or more "steps" with different logic and layout.

For example, The first fragment has a listview with some buttons and second fragment slightly different and third fragment very different. All contained and changed dynamically in the Dialog.

Is it a good or appropriate way to design this by having a `DialogFragment` as a parent container and within that parent container I just change fragments with say... some click event for example? Or would that be bad practice and is there a  better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to create an Activity with Dialog Theme.
You can put this inside activity tag in `AndroidManifest.xml` to achieve this:

```
<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" />
```

Edit:
Now present the fragments in the activity same as usual.
You can also start the activity with `startActivityForResult` and maintain the activity stack flow.

Comment: Thanks for your time. Is the activity placed in a dialog or do you have to do something else in order to achieve a "modal / dialog" look to it?

Comment: Create an activity in place of dialog. Instead of showdialog, startactivity. To make activity look like Dialog. Place the code I provided in AndroidManifest.xml in activity tag. Load the fragment in that activity.